How should I use custom models in PyCaret?
I am a newbie in PyCaret.
When I was doing experiments on time series forecasting, the library I used to compare and create models was the latest PyCaret.
When thinking of using the LSTM algorithm for prediction, I found that PyCaret did not provide native support for LSTM, so I manually implemented a scikit-learn API style model class as required by the official documentation.
However, the RMSE and other results of this class are very poor.
Did I write the code wrong?
Below is the code I implemented in Jupyter Notebook.
class LSTMModelClass(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, output_size):
        super(LSTMModelClass, self).__init__()
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, batch_first=True)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)

    def forward(self, x):
        out, _ = self.lstm(x)
        out = out[-1,:]
        out = self.fc(out)
        return out
        
class LSTM(BaseForecaster):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, output_size,learning_rate=0.001,epochs=10):
        super(LSTM, self).__init__()
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.output_size = output_size
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.epochs = epochs
        self.model = LSTMModelClass(self.input_size, self.hidden_size, self.num_layers, self.output_size)
        
    def fit(self, y, fh=None, X=None):
        if X is not None:
            X = X.loc[y.index]
        loss_function = nn.MSELoss()
        optimizer = optim.Adam(self.model.parameters(), lr=self.learning_rate)
        X = torch.from_numpy(np.array(X)).float()
        y = torch.from_numpy(np.array(y)).float()
        # 训练循环
        self.model = self.model.train()
        for i in range(self.epochs):
            outputs = self.model(X)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss = loss_function(outputs, y)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            print(f'Epoch [{i+1}/{epochs}], Loss: {loss.item()}')
        return self

    def predict(self, fh, X=None):
        # Make forecasts.

        # Parameters
        # ----------
        # fh : array-like
        #     The forecasters horizon with the steps ahead to to predict.
        #     Default is
        #     one-step ahead forecast, i.e. np.array([1]).
        # X : pd.DataFrame, optional (default=None)
        #     Exogenous variables are ignored

        # Returns
        # -------
        # y_pred : pandas.Series
        #     Returns series of predicted values.
        # Make forecasts.
        self.model = self.model.eval()
        X_tensor = torch.from_numpy(np.array(X)).float()
        y_tensor = self.model(X_tensor)
        if y_tensor.is_cuda:
            y_tensor = y_tensor.cpu()
        numpy_array = y_tensor.detach().numpy()
        y_pred = pd.DataFrame(numpy_array,index = X.index)
        print(y_pred)
        return y_pred
    def check_is_fitted(estimator, attributes=None, *, msg=None, all_or_any=all):
        return

I implemented the MLP algorithm using the same code (just replacing the LSTMModelClass class), but the results of MLP were worse than those of LSTM.
Quantitative results of the experiment
I have tried adjusting network parameters, but the above results are the best results that automatic parameter tuning can give.
I also tried replacing the network with MLP, but the effect was even worse, and even both were significantly worse than several simple models built into PyCaret.
I think it should not be a problem with the data, because the built-in model works very well (the input is (101872, 28), after excluding the target value, there are 27 features in total, a total of 101872 rows. Because of a bug in PyCaret, the Index is in Int format instead of time)

batch_first=True so I think in forward() it should be out = out[:, -1] (to pull out the final time step over all samples). Currently it's the other way round (pulling out all timesteps of the last sample).

Because the input is a 2D Tensor(101872,128), there is no batch parameter, so I think batch_first=True has no effect. If I change to out = out[:, -1] the output will be composed of 101872 1D vectors, which will conflict with the dimension parameter of fc. I also think that the last time step of all samples should be used, but in any case there is no way to match fc. Is it because I didn't deal with the problem of time window division?

I see, yes I think you're right. I think an problem here is the length of the sequence - in my understanding LSTMs tend to be used up to a few hundred time steps, after which they might struggle. Are you able to go for a batch-training approach, where you break the 10, 1872 sequence into windows of, say, 100 steps?

Thanks a lot! I tried dividing the data into small batches of 100 steps and the model was more than ten times better than before! Thank you very much for your answer. I naively thought PyCaret could handle it automatically. But it turns out that manual division is still needed.

Great, I'm glad to hear it's working a lot better.
